# Eclipse, Basic JSP and Apache Tomcat

Tags: html, eclipse, apache, jsp, tomcat

I am well versed with the servlet thingy.

I am trying to make a project with the help of jsp. I made a web project on eclipse named *website* and then I copied some commands like `jsp:include`. At first it ran properly showing all the context, but after that it just gave errors like:

`Http page not found`

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Also I did not make changes in the `web.xml` file. I don't know if any change is required in that file.

```
    <html><head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Yo</title>
<jsp:include page="Header.html"/>

</head>
<body>
<!--<div id="header" style="background-color:orange;width:1360px;height:120px">
<h1><style="margin-bottom:0;"><font size="72px" color="white" ><center>
UTTAR PRADESH TECHNICAL UNIVERSITY
</center></font></h1>
</div>-->
WebSite under contruction.
<table width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >
<tr>
<td width="15%"> <jsp:include page="LeftPanel.html"  flush="true"/>Left Panel </td>
<td width="70%" class="alignment">
    <table width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >
    <tr><td><jsp:include page="Header.html" flush="true"/></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</td>
<!--<td width="15%"> <jsp:include page="RightPanel.html" flush="true"/>Right               Panel</td>-->
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

This is the version I made but it's not working and even the simple code like below is not getting deployed properly.

```
 <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Watch Initial D live Online Free</title>
<jsp:include page="Header.html"/>
</head>
<body>
Hey Whats Up just Testing..
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i got it running .. actually my apache server was conflicting with oracle 10g server at port 8080 ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found out the reason why it got clashed and stopped responding .
it was **conflicting** with the **oracle 10g server** at the port *8080*
so i switched the port to **80 of my apache tomcat server** .
now it works properly .